# Add row in kendo grid after click in button

Tags: jquery, button, kendo-ui, onclick, grid

I would like to add new row with data in kendo grid, but button Edit/Add are outside grid-window. In my case, after click button "add" I open new window with empty gaps  and after click "submit" i would like to see new data in grid.
How should I do this?

Comment: you mean to say that the grid is not reloaded after adding the data, right ?

Comment: I could be reloaded after adding the data , but I don't want to use button like here [link](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/mvvm).I would like to select data in eg.window3 -> submit and after that reload grid in e.g window 2.

Comment: you mean that you need a popup add/edit ?

Comment: Yes, I need a popup add/edit

Comment: have you tries this [link](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-editable.mode)

Comment: check out the below answer @Agnieszka

Answer (score 0):

I guess for your requirement a **popup Add function** is a sufficient one.
[Check this out](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-popup) it will be useful for you.